# Adding file description to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in ASP.NET which displays certain files and users can download depending on their role. I have managed to populate from the directory without an issue. However my problem is I need to add a description column for each file i.e.

Test.pdf will have a some description
Test2.pdf will have another description and so on

I can't seem to figure out how to added value to the description column. The filename column values are of course coming from the directory.

Please find below my code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

And the backend C# code is

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/document/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                // How can I add the description name for each file
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: where do you plan on getting this description?

Comment: @ethorn10 I'm planning on storing them in a database and retrieving them from there

Comment: and you'll match descriptions with filenames how?

Comment: @ethorn10 We've decided we're going to have the filenames and description in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, creating a  `Class` to represent the data you want to display will be best.

```
public class FileDetails
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you will create a `List` of the above class.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/document/"));
List<FileDetails> files = new List<FileDetails>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
 //Line 1
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath); 
 // Line 2
 files.Add(new FileDetails() { FileName = filename, 
                             FileDescription = filename+"This is a test file" });
}
GridView1.DataSource = files;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can definitely use different ways for populating  `FileDescription` field above in Line 2.

ASPX code will be similar to below :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileDescription " HeaderText="File Description" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but wouldn't this add `This is a test file` next to every file? Would you know how I can make it more dynamic?

Comment: yes, you can use a variable inside foreach loop as: int i = 0; foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{ 
 // Line 2
 files.Add(new FileDetails() { FileName = filename, 
                             FileDescription = filename+i }); i++;
}